# Disk Utility cannot erase USB drive (error -69877: couldn't open device)

Tags: macos, disk-utility, catalina, sd-card, flash-memory

Disk Utility (macOS Catalina 10.15.2) fails to erase my USB drive (64GB key, currently formatted in exFAT).

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *64.1 GB    disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data Lexar                   63.9 GB    disk2s2
```

I've tried a bunch of commands that I've found here and there in the terminal, but none of them worked, like:

```
➜  ~ diskutil eraseVolume exFAT MyName /dev/disk2
Started erase on disk2
Unmounting disk
Error: -69888: Couldn't unmount disk
```

```
➜  ~ diskutil eraseVolume exFAT MyName /dev/disk2s2    
Started erase on disk2s2 Lexar
Unmounting disk
Erasing
Error: -69760: Unable to write to the last block of the device
```

```
➜  ~ diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 MYSD MBRFormat /dev/disk2
Started erase on disk2
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Error: -69877: Couldn't open device
```

```
➜  ~ diskutil eraseDisk free EMPTY /dev/disk2
Started erase on disk2
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Error: -69877: Couldn't open device
```

My USB drive appears as read only when i do CMD+I, I tried repairing the permissions but that failed too.

```
➜  ~ diskutil resetUserPermissions /dev/disk2 `id -u`
Ready to reset user permissions on disk2
Error encountered attempting to reset permissions for user 501 home directory on disk2: Permissions are not enabled on the disk (-69861)
```

Thx in advance for the help :)

Comment: Can you unmount the disk in Finder and then try it?

Comment: In this case (erase to exFat via Disk Utility), it fails too, unable to write last to the last block of the device

Comment: Instead of posting screen captures, can you please input this as *text* because none of it is searchable.  To capture of the output of a command, simply pipe the output to `pbcopy`.  For example `disktutil list | pbcopy`, then [edit] the original question with the info you just captured.  Don't forget to format it!

Comment: I edited the question to replace the pictures

Answer (score 10):

<sup>*This is an attempt to write a canonical QA for this issue, as per the Meta post:  [Where is the list of canonical questions stored for Ask Different?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2418/where-is-the-list-of-canonical-questions-stored-for-ask-different) This answer is based off a number of pre-existing answers expect it to be periodically edited with the goal of becoming a comprehensive information resource*. <sup>*</sup></sup>

#### Can't Access the Device

If you're having an issue where you can't access the device there are a couple things to check first:

- Check for write protection.
- On SD cards, there is a physical "write lock" switch that may become enabled.  Make sure it's in the "up" position.  If it's [write protected on every SD](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/168065/119271) , you may have an issue with the logic board itself.
- On USB flash drives, there may be a physical switch or it may be write protected from via a write protect bit, or the chip may be modified from the factory.
- Make sure you have the correct privileges.  Sometimes the drive may have had user privileges assigned to them.  Using an Admin account will usually get around this.

#### Fixing the Device

There are a few steps you can take, but all are destructive to the data on the device.

1. **Erase Disk.**  As the name implies, this does a simple erase of the disk and marks the free space as "empty" with no file system  or partition scheme.

   ```
   $ diskutil eraseDisk free Empty /dev/diskX
   ```
2. **Re-partitition the Disk**.  I like to force a rewrite of the partition map to something that macOS is familiar with like a GPT partition and HFS+ file system.  You can use MS-DOS with MBR as well.  Use `diskutil listfilesystem` to get a full list of supported file systems.

   ```
   $ diskutil partitionDisk diskX 1 GPT HFS+ Untitled 100%   ← GPT with HFS Format

   $ disktuil partitionDisk diskX 1 MBR FAT32 UNTITLED 100%  ← MBR with MS-DOS
   ```
3. **Zero out the disk.**  Using this command writes zeros to every block of the *raw* device, meaning you're bypassing everything and accessing the device itself.  This is the nuclear option because it will overwrite every single spot on the device with a zero.  Triple check the device name!

   ```
   $ diskutil unmountDisk diskX            ← Only if necessary (you get a "Resource Busy")

   $ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/diskX bs=1m
   ```

---

If none of the above works, it's likely the device has failed.  On SD cards, this is actually quite common. Ask any photographer and they'll tell you that [SD cards fail](https://fstoppers.com/poll/how-often-do-sd-cards-really-fail-289251) usually in the middle of paid gig which is one of the reasons they now make [D-SLRs with dual memory slots](https://www.howtogeek.com/392378/what%E2%80%99s-the-big-deal-about-dual-storage-card-slots-for-cameras/)

---

#### <sup>*</sup> Existing Questions/Answers

- [Couldn't open device](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/224752/119271)
- [Disk Utility won't erase my USB flash drive ("Couldn't open device")](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/274009/119271)
- [How can I fix Error: -69877: Couldn't open device after interrupted formatting process?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/229967/119271)
- [Unable to format USB disk (Error: -69877: Couldn't open device)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/387325/119271)
- [Disk Utility Cannot erase USB Drive (Error: -69877: Couldn't open device)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/313845/119271)

Comment: 1. & 2. didn't work, I had tested them before.
So I tried 3. and it took 3 days to zero out the disk, but it's still not working unfortunately.

~ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk2 bs=1m
dd: /dev/disk2: end of device
61121+0 records in
61120+1 records out
64088969216 bytes transferred in 273592.584641 secs (234250 bytes/sec)

Comment: same problem, none of the proposed solutions here worked, even after `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2` I got `dd: /dev/disk2: Resource busy` when trying to wipe it with `dd`.

Comment: wait... it started working after I unplugged the device and plugged it back in...

Comment: I finally managed to restore my hard drive with solution 3. Took around 6 hours on a 2TB disk, and there's no progress indicator displayed during the process, but it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!