# Boot Question Mark. Unable to write to last block of the device

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, disk-utility, ssd, disk-format

I am having trouble with my MacBook Air a1465. Turning it on displays an image of a folder with a question mark inside. Looking for how to solve the problem, I tried to clean the NVRAM, with ALT + CMD + P + Q. NVMRAM was successfully cleaned but the issue was not resolved so I tried to reinstall the system through OS X Utilities. When turning on the computer I press the CMD + R keys, I correctly enter OS X Utilities. If I select Reinstall OS X option, a screen opens to install OS X Mountain Lion, but when selecting the disk no disk appears. Again in the menu of OS X Utilities, I enter the DIsk Utility option, here if the disk appears (120gb SSD), but when trying to format it or create a partition after a few minutes an error appears "Unable to write the last block of the device ”, and the disk disappears from the list. To see the disk again I have to clean the NVRAM again.

I tried erase with the formats Mac OS Extended (Journaled), Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted) and the message is always the same. I also tried to create a partition that occupies the entire disk with the same two formats, and I also get the same error .

I also tried to create a disk image so I could restore it later. I select New Image, try to save it to an external disk, and after a few minutes a message appears saying that the device is not configured.

I also want to comment that you start a Linux Live-CD, the computer starts correctly, but it never detects the disk, neither when installing the OS from the Kali Linux installation menu, nor after booting the Live-CD with the command fdisk -l.

I attach an image with information from the disc.

[image: ssd drive information]

TOSHIBA THNSN2128GSPS

EDIT:

output of **diskutil list**

[image: output_diskutil]

Comment: You made several attempts to install macOS and reformat the drive, they all failed. This *really* sounds like a defective SSD that needs to be replaced.

Comment: Linux format/partition utilities do some weird things to drives - I'm not a Linux person so I don't know what it's doing.  I've found that if you a) format the drive as FAT32 in Linux or b) if you properly erase and repartitions, you can fix this error.  See this answer for some methods:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/387460/119271

Comment: I think it may be corrupted, the only thing that makes me doubt that the disk is is that it does not recognize it when I try to reinstall OS X, nor does it recognize it when I try to install another operating system, eg Kali Linux or Ubuntu.

Comment: I started with option + cmd + r, and the system booted with OS X Catalina. I tried to reinstall macOS, but the installer cannot find the disk. So I tried to format the disk using Disk Utility, but it fails to complete the process.

Output command diskutil eraseDisk HFS + disk22 / dev / disk22:
Started erase on disk22
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
[ \ 0%..10%..20%..30%..40%..50% . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ] 50.0%
Error: -69877 Couldn't open device

Comment: The ssd was damaged. I solved the problem with a new SSD disk.